# How to loop for date range within two tables in sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please, can anyone give me any idea how to get all dates individually within a date range of  another table.

How to do 'not include 18 and 19' also: How do I rewrite stored procedure not to count as available middle dates(18,19) of Reservation table status 'Occupied'.

I have date range in Reservation table of :

```
CheckInDate (07/16/2014 12:00:00 AM)
CheckOutDate (07/20/2014 13:00:00 PM)

RoomNumber     CheckInDate                CheckOutDate               Status
   204         07/16/2014 12:00:00 AM     07/20/2014 13:00:00 PM     Occupied
```

But in my `AvailableTest` table, there is no date range. All records are going 
individual date. But in Reservation table they do not have individual date. 
They have range and how do I match that date range and my individual date from `AvailableTest` table.

```
RoomNumber     CheckInDate                CheckOutDate               Status
   204         07/16/2014 12:00:00 AM     07/16/2014 13:00:00 PM     Available
   204         07/17/2014 12:00:00 AM     07/17/2014 13:00:00 PM     Available
   204         07/18/2014 12:00:00 AM     07/18/2014 13:00:00 PM     Available
   204         07/19/2014 12:00:00 AM     07/19/2014 13:00:00 PM     Available
   204         07/20/2014 12:00:00 AM     07/20/2014 13:00:00 PM     Available
```

If someone check for available room within range of 07/18/2014 to 07/24/2014

```
   204         07/18/2014 12:00:00 AM     07/18/2014 13:00:00 PM     Available
   204         07/19/2014 12:00:00 AM     07/19/2014 13:00:00 PM     Available
   204         07/20/2014 12:00:00 AM     07/20/2014 13:00:00 PM     Available
```

should not available anymore but when I try to query out they only take out

```
   204         07/20/2014 12:00:00 AM     07/20/2014 13:00:00 PM     Available
```

and 18 and 19 is still come out as available.

It looks like they only know and try to match with `checkindate` and `checkoutdate`
only so they check 16 and 20 within the date range of 18 to 24(checking available). 
They don't know 18 and 19 is occupied also.

Here is my query

```
select distinct (at.RoomNumber), at.RoomID, '', '', '', '', '', '', at.CheckInDate, at.CheckOutDate
from AvailableTest at                       
   join Room r on r.RoomID = at.RoomID 
   join Reservations res on res.RoomID =r.RoomID where 
   ((at.CheckInDate between '07/18/2014 13:00:00 PM' and '07/24/2014 12:00:00 AM')
        or (at.CheckOutDate between '07/18/2014 13:00:00 PM' and '07/24/2014 12:00:00 AM'))
        and at.CheckOutDate not in ( SELECT CheckOutDate  
    FROM reservations rs WHERE ((CheckInDate BETWEEN '07/18/2014 13:00:00 PM' AND '07/24/2014 12:00:00 AM') OR (CheckOutDate BETWEEN '07/18/2014 13:00:00 PM' AND '07/24/2014 12:00:00 AM')) ) and at.CheckInDate  not in ( SELECT  CheckInDate FROM reservations rs WHERE ((at.CheckInDate BETWEEN '07/18/2014 13:00:00 PM' AND  '07/24/2014 12:00:00 AM') OR (at.CheckOutDate BETWEEN '07/18/2014 13:00:00 PM' AND '07/24/2014  12:00:00 AM')) )'
```

Comment: Just a guess, but you seem to be mixing 12hour and 24hour clocks. Is 12:00:00 AM 00:00:00 ?

Comment: What is the use of the `AvailableTest` table? What data you are maintaining in it?

Comment: hi Ruskin, i use only 24 hours range its coz of check out time must be 12:00 AM thus why I put

Comment: Hi Ramesh, AvailableTest is for use like a calendar. Its contanin RoomID      RoomNumber      CheckInDate      CheckOutDate       Status

Comment: Hi Ramesh, 57  ,  204  ,  07/16/2014 12:00:00 AM, 07/16/2014 13:00:00 PM AND Available under the column name. I did it for calendar table to get Available date and I try to take out all available room but not Occupied,Reserved and Maintenance Rooms from Reservation table. So I avoid not to available for the date of Occupied,Reserved and Maintenance from reservation table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking to only get rows from the AvailableTest table for dates that there are no rows in the Reservations table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    r.RoomNumber,
    at.RoomID ,
    '' ,
    '' ,
    '' ,
    '' ,
    '' ,
    '' ,
    at.CheckInDate ,
    at.CheckOutDate
FROM    AvailableTest at
    INNER JOIN Room r
        ON r.RoomID = at.RoomID
    INNER JOIN Reservations res
        ON res.RoomID = r.RoomID
WHERE at.CheckInDate NOT BETWEEN res.CheckInDate AND res.CheckOutDate
```

There are some design issues with your availabletest table.  As it seems you have a checkin/checkout columns though there are only rows for a single date.  Just adding a level of complication that isn't needed.  I know this as I worked for a Hotel Management company for 10 years.